# AWS S3 - how to enable regional endpoints for regions other than us-east-1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

The purpose of `enableRegionalUsEast1Endpoint` method associated with `AmazonS3ClientBuilder` in aws S3 SDK is to (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/S3ClientOptions.Builder.html#enableRegionalUsEast1Endpoint--)):

> "Enable resolving region us-east-1 as a regional endpoint instead of defaulting to the global endpoint"

But I do not see any similar methods that can enable resolving to any other regional endpoint, apart from `us-east-1`.

**Question:** What is the way to enable regional endpoint with AWS Java SDK, for regions other than `us-east-1`?

**Context:** My end goal is to be able to generate presigned URLs with regional domain e.g. `https://<BUCKET_NAME>.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/<KEY>...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each AWS client can be configured to use a specific endpoint within a region by calling the withEndpointConfiguration method when creating the client.

For example, to configure the Amazon S3 client to use the Europe (Ireland) Region, use the following code.

```
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
 .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(
      "https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
      "eu-west-1"))
 .withCredentials(CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER)
 .build();
```